# question about SNMP MIB file

Tags: snmp

i wanna know how can i create a new customize MIB file ?
i wanna create a MIB file and use it in LINUX that with this mib i wanna monitor an application

please help me

thanks

Comment: "wanna wanna wanna". Enough already.

Answer (score 2):

MIB files are created in a simple text editor (following the rules for SMIv2).  Then you'll need to turn it into code, modify the code to suit your data, compile it into an agent and run the agent.  Then you can use a management application to request the data from the agent.

Net-SNMP is the most popular linux stack for linux, so you might start with it's tutorials at http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/

Comment: thanks .. i've seen this page ..! but i need full book to learn all dimensions ..! Create new MIB and add application process status (for example : Oracle transactions )